# VSTO 'ClickOnce manifests' signing using Code Signing ECC SHA384

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, sha-3

I have a PowerPoint VSTO/C# project that is using the Visual Studio signing capability.
The project was using the `Sha256` code signing certificate and was working correctly.

I was able to select the correct signature in the Visual Studio signing tab by clicking on 'Select from Store...'.
[image: Select from store]

Recently I renewed the certificate to `DigiCert Global G3 Code Signing ECC SHA384 2021 CA1`. Since then, Visual Studio is not able to select my signature.

When I click on 'Select from Store...", I am getting the message:

> No certificates available. No certificates meet the application.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.11.5.

Is this a limitation of Visual Studio? If yes, is there a possibility to run a post build tool manually to perform the same operation?

Comment: According to document research and investigation, vs does not seem to support sha-3 for the time being.[February 2021 Deployment Notice - Microsoft Trusted Root Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/2021/feb2021) and [2019 SHA-2 Code Signing Support requirement for Windows and WSUS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus-64d1c82d-31ee-c273-3930-69a4cde8e64f)

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other options for manually signing the VSTO file after build?

Comment: [Does it help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/delay-sign)? `Delay-sign an assembly`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and asked about it there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-studio-doesnt-detect-digicert-co/10135932?port=1025&fsid=d5a2dbf9-137f-411b-aec3-06d687a8d0cf&entry=problem.
Mage tool used by Visual Studio to sing ClickOnce manifests doesn't support ecc public keys. Also I'm not sure if Mage tool supports sha384.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RSA 256, I also bought an Code signing cert that is ECC and it isn't supported

Answer (score 0):

The certificate authority informed us that since jun 2023 the sha256 is no longer available.
Strange thing is that the signtool does support the certificate.